# How to extract first sentence in string with 8 or less words?

Tags: r

How to extract first (or last) sentence with 8 or less words (or another condition)? For example I have a Text

```
text <- "The quick brown fox. This is wonderful!"
```

What's the most elegant way to extract first sentence/last sentence based on quantity of words from this text?

Comment: In r?! That will be cool. Could do it in Java in two flicks of the wrist.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if we want to find the first sentence with less than 4 words, don't think it is the most elegant way:

```
text <- "The quick brown fox. This is wonderful!"
split <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\. "))
number_words <- sapply(split, function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))))
split[which(number_words < 4)[1]]
[1] "This is wonderful!"
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, two flicks of the wrist to organize the information. I added another sentence for complexity:

```
text="The quick brown fox. This is wonderful! A sentence with eight or more words in it?"
sentence <- strsplit(text, "(?<=[.?!]) ?", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
count <- lengths(strsplit(sent, " "))
condition <- count < 8 
data.frame(sentence, count, condition)
#                                     sentence count condition
# 1                       The quick brown fox.     4      TRUE
# 2                         This is wonderful!     3      TRUE
# 3 A sentence with eight or more words in it?     9     FALSE

#First
df$sentence[df$condition][1]
#[1] "The quick brown fox."

#Last
tail(df$sentence[df$condition],1)
#[1] "This is wonderful!"
```